# CosmosDB access only specific records for user

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to achieve completely "serverless" status for my app with some simple CRUD operations, so my current approach is Blazor WASM on front-end and CosmosDB as records storage. I've configured AAD (Azure Active Directory) authentication in my Blazor App, and as for now, I'm wondering, if there is any way to to restrict CosmosDB client in Blazor to read only records which belongs to current user specifically (each record has UserId field)?
So, the main thing that I want to know, if it is possible at all?
Because I've found a plenty of different documentation, but because of lack of experience with Azure, I can't completely figure it out.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. The main solution I would like to approach - completely avoid any backend (API/servers/Azure Functions), because I really want to make it just Client App <-> CosmosDB, and AFAIK Firebase with JavaScript FrontEnd allows to do such a trick, but I'm interested in Azure-specific solution here

Comment: I'd say [resource tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data?tabs=using-primary-key#resource-tokens) are the way to go here.

Comment: @PeterBons Yeah, I've also found that in docs, but I'm a little bit confused, are they somehow restrict the records itself? I mean, could user A read records of user B?

Comment: To avoid any API or backend or functions just means that you move that logic directly into your Blazor code. This can be achieved in many different ways, ultimately you will need to map the user to the cosmos containers and resource tokens are one way to do this. There is no real Azure trick to this, it is all in your application design, try using API management to map the auth user to specific resource tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a simple walkthrough for Blazor, but overall the process would be similar to this guidance: [Authenticate Users with an Azure Cosmos DB Document Database and Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-cosmosdb-auth) but it requires setup of an API service to broker the connections, which you specifically have asked to avoid.

If you didn't use an automated `Resource Token Broker` then in your logic somewhere you would need to store a map of somekind to resolve the Cosmos DB [Resource Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data?tabs=using-primary-key#resource-tokens) for the logged in user.

In the following guidance, replace Xamarin with *Blazor* and Facebook with *Azure AD*:

[image: typical resource token process]

1. On login, the *Blazor* WASM contacts Azure App Service to initiate an authentication flow.
2. Azure App Service performs an Open Auth flow with Azure AD. After the authentication flow completes, the *Blazor* WASM receives an access token.
3. The *Blazor* WASM uses the access token to request a resource token from the resource token broker.
4. The resource token broker uses the access token to request the user's identity from Azure AD. The user's identity is then used to request a resource token from Cosmos DB, which is used to grant read/write access to the authenticated user's partitioned collection.
5. The *Blazor* WASM uses the resource token to directly access Cosmos DB resources with the permissions defined by the resource token.

Comment: Thank you very much!)
So, as I've got your mind, I still need some backend that will resolve a resource token to my App?
And there is completely no way to access a CosmosDB securely on client, without giving access to all the records or connection string

Comment: The issue why we need logic in the middle, which doesn't have to be a separate process, it can be within the blazor app as a server component, is that you have 2 different authentication streams. You are using AAD as a convenience for users and to manage users, the management of Cosmos resource tokens is not very user or self service friendly and importantly requires an admin credential to manage the creation of tokens, for security reasons we want to offload that workflow to another more secure process.

Comment: It is a super strange request to NOT want an additional App Service or Function App to host some of this logic, that is certainly the _Azure_ way to do this, so to ask for an Azure way without using Azure is like pushing a heavy object up a steep incline, you can do it, but it will take more effort to fight against the natural order of things. In a CodeMentor.IO session I would try exploring this thought process of yours to understand more of the angle you are trying to approach this from.

Comment: Using multiple app services or functions is how we achieve a serverless app. It actually sounds like what you want is a "thick" or fully self contained client. (Which is _very_ different to _serverless_) Thick clients are risky because you need to deploy the secrets within the client code and client code is "out there" and very easy to inspect, decompile and ultimately steal secrets. Thick clients in an Azure stack represent the greatest security vulnerabilities. Your app will never be totally offline if it is using cosmosDB so you might as well embrace services and functions when necessary

Comment: Yeah, I've got your mind. Please, don't get me wrong, I'm not against using Azure Functions layer (or some another backend) for it, of course it is the most adequate and convenient way to create such web apps, the whole sense of my question was: If it is possible at all, without any security risks. So, I just had an interest to try to do so, just for fun or something like that, so, this is not a "strict" requirement.
Thank you very much for explanation, I saw that it is impossible without security risks, so, this was the main point which I wanted to get :)